# Why do some transformers trip circuit breaker. Eg a ups transformer. I need a soft start resistor details

Tags: transformer, soft-starter

I need a soft start for a ups transformer. Because when I power it with 230v ac it trips the breaker. I need a diagram to build my own soft start circuit.

Comment: How many times in ten starts does it trip the breaker?

Answer (score 1):

It is all about the inrush current ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current), [2](https://www.ametherm.com/blog/inrush-current/transformer-inrush-current-40va-transformer#:%7E:text=Transformer%20inrush%20current%20describes%20a,amount%20of%20current%20when%20energized.)). When the primary gets magnetised, the amount of current it needs to build up a magnetic field before collapsing and transferring the energy to the secondary can be 10 times higher than its nominal rating.

An example of an inrush current limiting circuit or a [soft starter](http://dangerousprototypes.com/blog/2016/01/08/10a-variac-soft-starter/) is the one provided by Steve Gardner but for a Variable Auto-transformer, or Variac